# Show that the determinant of areas is non-negative.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, determinant

> Consider a sequence of discs $U_1, U_2,\dots,U_n \subset \mathbb R^2$. Let $S_{ij}$ denote the area of the intersection of $U_i$ and $U_j$. Prove that
> $$\begin{vmatrix} 
> S_{11} & S_{12} & … & S_{1n} \\ 
> S_{21} & S_{22} & ... & S_{2n} \\ 
> … & … & \ddots & … \\ S_{n1} & 
> S_{n2} & … & S_{nn} 
> \end{vmatrix} \ge 0$$

---

For $n = 2$, we have
$$\begin{vmatrix} S_{11} & S_{12} \\ S_{21} & S_{22} \end{vmatrix} = S_{11}S_{22} - S_{12}S_{21} \ge 0$$
since the diagonal elements are the largest. So the claim holds. I was planning to go through induction but it seems like to get a big deal to see how the determinant will change after adding a new disc to the collection.
What we also have are the matrix is symmetric so that $S_{ij} = S_{ji}$ and therefore the eigenvalues are real (I don't see any use of this though).

Comment: This is an interesting question. Where did you find it?

Comment: @davidlowryduda It is from a book (not in English) and the solution is, unfortunately, not provided.

Comment: Notably, this condition implies that the matrix must be positive semidefinite (since each principal submatrix has the same structure with respect to some set of disks)

Comment: Ok. So what book is it from?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, right